# output the top stack value with write system call

Tags: assembly, stack, nasm

I'm trying to output the top value on the stack (here it is "6").
But I get garbage.
Am I missing something ?

```
push rax
mov     rax, 1      ; 'write' syscall number
mov     rdi, 1      ; stdout descriptor
mov     rsi, rsp    ; rsp is the address where number "6" is stored by "push rax" before
mov     rdx, 1      ; string length
syscall
```

Comment: That looks correct. What exactly is in `rax`? Note you need text. If it's the value `6` that is a non-printable control character `ACK`. See [man ascii](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html)

Comment: thanks!  rax was holding 6,   but should have been 54 (ascii code for character "6")

Comment: If you want for output an ASCII string of decimal digits that represent the number, you'll have to prepare that in a buffer, like in [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894)